# Python read tsv file and evaluate

Tags: python, file, text-parsing

I have tsv file which is prepared like:

```
*Settings*                          
Force, Tags FakeTag                     
Resource    ../../robot_resources/global.tsv                        

*Test, Cases*                           
Testcase1   [Documentation] PURPOSE:                    
    ... Test, checking,,                
    ...                     
    ...                     
    ... PRECONDITION:                   
    ... set,                    
    ... make, sure, that,                   
    ...                     
    ...                                     
    [Setup] stopProcessAndWaitForIt                 
    startAdvErrorTrace                      
    startAdvDumpEvents                      
    stopProcessAndWaitForIt                             
    stopAndDownloadAdvDumpEvents                                

Testcase2   [Documentation] PURPOSE:                    
    ... Test, checking,, if,                
    ...                     
    ...                     
    ... PRECONDITION:
```

What i want to do is:
- start reading file from *Test, Cases*
- read separatly every testcase: testcase1, testcase2..n (every testcase starts without tab, testcase body starts with tab)
- evaluate if all testcases has expresions "startAdvErrorTrace" "startAdvDumpEvents" etc
I have in tsv about 50 testcases and want evaluate all file

I'm totally green in developing. I have found some ideas like read csv file as tsv. But i don't know how to achieve my expectations

Comment: I have reformatted your question - hoping I didn't break anything doing so. If I did, sorry - just rollback to the original state by clicking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21601777/revisions). But it seems that this isn't a TSV file in the sense that it's made up of tabulator-separated values. Where does this file come from?

Comment: Thank You, now it looks like it should be. I didn't know how to format it properly :)

Comment: OK,  but then that definitely isn't a TSV file, and Python's `csv` module won't be able to help you with that. I'll think up something else.

Comment: it's storen on disc as a suite.tsv and it's output from Robot Framework. So i guess it must be tsv file :)

Comment: Just because someone uses a file extension doesn't mean that the file conforms to a certain format...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what file format this is, but you can do something like this:

```
items = ("startAdvErrorTrace", "startAdvDumpEvents") # add more as desired
import re
with open("testfile") as infile:
    # skip contents until Test Cases
    contents = re.search(r"(?s)\*Test, Cases\*.*", infile.read())
    cases = contents.split("\n\n") # Split on two consecutive newlines
    for case in cases:
        if not all(item in case for item in items)
            print("Not all items found in case:")
            print(case)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    kosmos ("E:\\Repozytoriumtsuites\\Communication.tsv")
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 5, in kosmos
    cases = contents.split("\n\n") # Split on two consecutive newlines
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: def kosmos(testfile):
 with open(testfile) as infile:
     # skip contents until Test Cases
     contents = re.search(r"(?s)\*Test, Cases\*.*", infile.read())
     cases = contents.split("\n\n") # Split on two consecutive newlines
     for case in cases:
  if not all(item in case for item in items):
      print("Not all items found in case:")
      print(case)

Comment: Are there really two asterisks around the text "Test, Cases"? The regex presumes that they are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script to parse the flags per Testcase. The output is:

```
Flags per testcase:
{1: ['startAdvErrorTrace', 'startAdvDumpEvents'], 2: []}
```

And the script is:

```
usage = {}
flags = ('startAdvErrorTrace', 'startAdvDumpEvents')
with(open(testfile)) as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    start_parsing = False
    for line in lines:
        if 'Test, Cases' in line:
            start_parsing = True
            continue

        if parse_cases:
            if 'Testcase' in line:
                case_nr = int(re.findall('\d+', line)[0])
                usage[case_nr] = []
                continue

            for flag in flags:
                if flag in line:
                    usage[case_nr].append(flag)

print 'Flags per testcase:'
usage
```

Hope that helps.